# pg_search model and controller relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

This probably is a nooby one. I'm building a search form.

In the model document.rb, I have this :

```
pg_search_scope :search_full_text, 
                :against => :full_text, 
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :prefix => true
                        }
                    }
```

and in documents_controller.rb, I have :

```
def find
    $results = Document.search_full_text(params[:ch_acte][:text])
end
```

But NOTHING gets send to the database. The server log only says:

```
Started POST "/documents/find" for ::1 at 2017-01-19 08:48:07 +0100
Processing by DocumentsController#find as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZkqVYMuqMqnUjLer/FVdBdtv4cycp71dXqPQw6j0mfHKX5ptin7p7YiYFj8bNtjciQDmHzbKtBnZoILpGGvl8Q==", "ch_acte"=>{"text"=>"complet", "words"=>"", #[cut for brievity]}, "commit"=>"Cherche"}
Rendering documents/find.html.erb within layouts/messources
Rendered documents/find.html.erb within layouts/messources (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 216ms (Views: 210.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Other than the method pg_search_scope in the model and calling that method in the controller, what must I do to get this sent to the database?

When I run `Document.search_full_text("esp")` in rails console, it works fine.

**UPDATE**

I added this in `documents/find.html.erb`  :

```
<% $results.each do |m| %>
    <p>The id is <%= m.id %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

I get an page that displays my menu, and only white after that...

Comment: fix  documents_models.rb in your question to documents_controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand that Rails tries to be as performant as possible.  When you build a search it does NOT execute until you attempt to access the results of the search.

So you would do...

```
def find
  @documents = Document.search_full_text(params[:ch_acte][:text])
end
```

Then in your `find.html.erb` you might do...

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <%= document.name %>
<% end %>
```

The query is *only* executed when the `@documents.each` line is executed to retrieve the documents... i.e. only when it needs to be executed.

Comment: Very interesting, do u know if this behavior is documented anywhere?

Comment: @Joel_Blum It's the way `ActiveRecord_Relation` objects work (which is what you create when using a scope or where on an `ActiveModel`) -- I can't specifically find documentation but it's a fundamental feature. The reason the code executed immediately in console or IRB is that console automatically calls an inspect on all lines. If you wanted to bypass this behavour in console you can do `Document.search_full_text("esp"); false` and so the inspect operates on `false` instead of the ActiveRecord_Relation.

Comment: And the reason it works this way... you can do `@objects = Object.where(name: "Smith)` and then `@objects = @objects.where(status: 'Active')` and so on and so forth, bulding exactly the query you need over muitple lines and then only executing a single query when you actually need the data.

Comment: @Joel_Blum forgot to tag you on the above ^

Comment: Also try printing '$results.count'  before the loop to see if you found any records.

Comment: Got it !! Routing problem and then a namespace problem where I put the html.erb in the admin namespace....